# Convert bytes data inside a string to a true bytes object

Tags: python, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

In Python 3, I have a string like the following:

```
mystr = "\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00"
```

This string was read from a file and it is the bytes representation of some text. To be clear, **this is a unicode string**, not a `bytes` object.

I need to transform `mystr` into a `bytes` object like the following:

```
mybytes = b"\x00\x00\x01\x01\x80\x02\xc0\x02\x00"
```

Notice that the translation should be literal. I don't want to encode the string.

Running `.encode('utf-8')` will escape the `\`.

It I manually copy and past the content into a `bytes` string, then everything works. What I couldn't find anywhere is how could I convert it without copy+paste.

Comment: `bytes(bytearray(ord(i) for i in mystr))` seems to work ... though I feel like there should be a better way.  Maybe the better way is to figure out how to not end up in this situation in the first place?  :-)

Comment: @mgilson thanks! I was thinking about that but this is what I have. Reading the file in `'rb'` gives be `"\\x00\\x00..."`, which is not what I want. Looking for something unrelated I found the solution I posted below.

Comment: I ended up deleting my answer because it didn't really work. There were some extra characters being printed in the middle that I hadn't noticed before.

Comment: "Running `.encode('utf-8')` will escape the `\`. " No, it won't. There isn't a `\` to escape in the string shown here. If the file actually contains backslashes, lowercase xs etc. then that is a separat problem; and you will see the backslashes be escaped if you view a `repr` of the string, even without changing anything. However, `.encode('utf-8')` **will** corrupt the data (assuming each Unicode code point is intended to represent one byte) by prepending a 0xc2 byte before the 0x80, and 0xc3 before the 0xc0.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question was intended to be, but it's one of these duplicates for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mystr.encode("latin-1")` is what you want.